# Will Inner join allow duplicates?

Tags: sql

if join two tables using inner join method will it return duplicate values ?

Comment: The answer is yes, if there are any.

Comment: If there are duplicate keys in the tables being joined.

Comment: What does "return duplicate values" mean? Do you mean, return two rows that are duplicates of each other? Or do you mean something about values for a column or subrow in a row or rows? You say "will" but do you mean "might"? Do you understand that "duplicate" means something special involving nulls in SQL, different from "where each column has the same value in both, possibly both NULL"? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, if there are duplicate values.

If you have `CUSTOMERS` table:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

and ORDERS table as follows:

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| OID | DATE                | CUSTOMER_ID | AMOUNT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   3000 |
| 100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   1500 |
| 101 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |           2 |   1560 |
| 103 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |           4 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

Then inner join will give result:

```
SELECT  ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
     FROM CUSTOMERS
     INNER JOIN ORDERS
     ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

This would produce the following result:

```
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
| ID | NAME     | AMOUNT | DATE                |
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  3 | kaushik  |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |   1560 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |   2060 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: No example returning duplicates?

Comment: what if customer table also had two rows for ID=3

Comment: @jarlh the example shows duplicate record already. Id=3 is duplicate here.

Comment: That's a duplicate column value, but the rows are not duplicated, since there are other columns with different values.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with duplicate rows in both tables.

```
select * from customers;
 id |    name     | age |  address
----+-------------+-----+-----------
  1 | Ramesh      |  32 | Ahmedabad
  2 | Khilan      |  25 | Delhi
  3 | kaushik     |  23 | Kota          <-- id 3 "kaushik"
  3 | kaushik_two |  23 | Ahmedabad     <-- appears twice
  4 | Chaitali    |  25 | Mumbai
  5 | Hardik      |  27 | Bhopal
  6 | Komal       |  22 | MP
  7 | Muffy       |  24 | Indore
(8 rows)


select * from orders;
 oid |        date         | customer_id | amount
-----+---------------------+-------------+--------
 102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   3000    <-- reference to customer 3 
 100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   1500    <-- also appears twice
 101 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |           2 |   1560
 103 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |           4 |   2060
 104 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |         100 |   3900
(5 rows)
```

#### Inner Join

Produces duplicated rows for "kaushik" and "kaushik_two".

```
select id, name, amount, date 
from customers 
inner join orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id;

 id |    name     | amount |        date
----+-------------+--------+---------------------
  2 | Khilan      |   1560 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00
  3 | kaushik     |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00  <-- first pair
  3 | kaushik     |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00
  3 | kaushik_two |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00  <-- second pair
  3 | kaushik_two |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00
  4 | Chaitali    |   2060 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00
(6 rows)
```